# angular 2: disabled not working properly

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have defined a boolean in my typescript called `readOnlyMode`, so when it's true everything should be disabled. I use `[disabled]="readOnlyMode"` for all elements in HTML that should be disabled. I am having trouble with custom HTML component which I made by myself. When I use above notation I get error:

```
Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'disabled' since it isn't a known property of 'app-color…, …}
```

HTML code causing this issue:

```
<app-color-palette style="position:relative; z-index:2;"
                                     [disabled]="readOnlyMode"
                                     [(selectedColorIndex)]="categoryDefinitionModel.Color">
</app-color-palette>
```

If I use disabled without brackets, It compiles but it doesn't disable the component.

Comment: An [mcve] must include that component - does it have that input property?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`disabled` is not a default property. You have to specify it in your custom component as:

```
@Input() disabled: boolean;
```

And then specify the behaviour in your component what it should look like / do when it is disabled.

Answer (score 1):

`[disabled]` doesn't come as 'build-in' attribute for components. In order to make it work, you could, for example, add `@Input() disabled`  in  property list. And then use `[disabled]=disabled` on that component elements that you wish to disable.